# Why is geemap.Map() showing a AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'?

Tags: python, attributeerror, google-earth-engine, geemap

I have this code, but its doesn't show up the maps (output). I don't know what is the error.

```
import geemap
Map=geemap.Map()
Map
```

After running the above code, I get the error "AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'"

I have also tried the code below, but this one gives the error "AttributeError: module 'ee' has no attribute 'Reducer'
"

```
import ee
ee.Authenticate()
import geemap
Map=geemap()
Map
```

I have an account on google earth engine and both the codes demand access link but after entering the link, these errors show up. I have also tried changing browsers of Jupyter lab to Google, Firefox and edge.....but still no progress.

Comment: `Callable` was moved from the `collections` module to `collections.abc` back in Python 3.3.  You must be using a really old version of `geemap` if it's still looking for this class in the old location.

Comment: @jasonharper I have installed the geemap just 2 days ago.....at first it was working fine but then I updated google client api and restarted the kernel. From then on the problem began. Maybe reinstalling might prove to be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and fixed it by downgrading my python version to be less than 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was informed [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/httplib2shim/issues/15), to solve this I edited the httplib2shim package

in
C:\Users\USERxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\httplib2shim_*init*_.py

Changing the line 45:

45 if isinstance(proxy_info, collections.Callable):

for

45 if isinstance(proxy_info, collections.**abc**.Callable):

and it worked fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem in one easy way. The new python file name and the built-in function name conflict are modified, change the name of the Python file.

Comment: And Pro.Wu provided the other answers: https://github.com/giswqs/geemap/discussions/243